# Error while trying toopen the requirements file

Tags: termux

I've used the command `pip install -r requirements.txt`(see in image1) it didn't work so I tried the command `py -2.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip`(see in image2) and it also didn't work
It show me the error `ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'`
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cAyX.png)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLkRC.png)

Answer (score 1):

Type `$ ls -l ~/fsociety/newDir` to verify the ACTUAL name of the requirements-file.
The name you tried with obviously does not exist.

Besides that; python 2.7 is obsolete since some time, so you will not be able to do certain things, e.g. updating pip may well fail of that reason alone.